# PostgreSQL - splitting rows using regex

Tags: regex, database, postgresql

I have got a table that has got colums ID, name and description. Table looks like:

```
ID    |  Name | Model
1     |  Ford | Focus 3
2.1-3 |  Opel | 1. Astra 2
      |       | 2. Vectra 2
      |       | 3. Vectra 3
3.1-2 | Toyota| Avensis 2; Micra 
4.1-2 |  Opel | (various versions) 1. Astra
      |       | (various versions) 2. Vectra
5.1-3 | Mazda | MX5; GTR; MX4
```

And I would like to split it into new rows using "regexp_split_to_table"
To get result like this:

```
ID    |  Name | Description
1     |  Ford | Focus 3
2.1   |  Opel | Astra 2
2.2   |  Opel | Vectra 2
2.3   |  Opel | Vectra 3
3.1   | Toyota| Avensis
3.2   | Toyota| Micra
4.1   |  Opel | Astra
4.2   |  Opel | Vectra
5.1   | Mazda | MX5
5.2   | Mazda | GTR
5.3   | Mazda | MX4
```

How to do it using postresql and update main table after that?

Big thanks for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't do that at all, because your new table is still not normalized. Yes, there are many examples of breaking normalization intentionally for the sake of easier coding and then getting better solutions, but in your case I can't see any potential use of that method. Just to give an example: You even wouldn't be able to list all models of all manufacturers in a reasonable query. This will lead nowhere, so better read about database normalization first and rethink your model before updating the records. Cheers.

Comment: @MyBrainHurts, I've corrected my model. Now it suppose to be right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it is impossible for several reasons:

Your data is not ordered, for your example it is possible to have something like

```
ID    |  Name | Description
      |       | (year)  2. 2004
1     |  Ford | Some text
5.1-3 | Mazda | Petrol; 1.9; 3-doors
      |       | 2. Diesel
2.1-3 |  Opel | 1. Astra
      |       | 3. 2005
3     | Toyota| 2001; Petrol; 1.8 TDI
4.1-2 |  Opel | (model) 1. Vectra
```

Just try something like

```
drop table if exists my_ugly_table;
create table my_ugly_table as select generate_series(1,3) as x, generate_series(1,3) as y;
select * from my_ugly_table;
update my_ugly_table set y = 4 where x = 2;
select * from my_ugly_table;
```

and you will have

first result:

```
 x | y 
---+---
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
 3 | 3
(3 rows)
```

second result:

```
 x | y 
---+---
 1 | 1
 3 | 3
 2 | 4
(3 rows)
```

As you can see row order was changed.

Next, your goal is wrong at the point that you want to keep in the ID some valuable data like `1.2, 1.3` and so on. ID must be just a unique identifier of the row and nothing else. Ideally you have no any knowledge about values of IDs - them just exists.

However you can try do do something with your original data using `plpgsql` or something like:

First of all create table where we will performing something bad with our data:

```
create table models_t as select * from models m where 1=2;
```

It will create empty table `models_t` with structure same to table `models`.

Finally for them lets create truly PK:

```
alter table models_t add mt_id serial not null primary key;
```

Next lets fill it by data:

```
do language plpgsql $$
declare
  p_rec models;
  c_rec models;
begin
  p_rec := null;
  for c_rec in (select * from models) loop
    p_rec.id := coalesce(c_rec.id, p_rec.id);
    p_rec.name := coalesce(c_rec.name, p_rec.name);
    p_rec.description := c_rec.description;
    insert into models_t values (p_rec.id, p_rec.name, p_rec.description);
    raise notice '% %', c_rec.id, c_rec.name;
  end loop;
end; $$;
```

Only one result of it is that we have table without gaps like:

```
postgres=# select * from models_t;
  id   |  name  |     description      | mt_id 
-------+--------+----------------------+-------
 1     | Ford   | Some text            |     1
 2.1-3 | Opel   | 1. Astra             |     2
 2.1-3 | Opel   | 2. Diesel            |     3
 2.1-3 | Opel   | 3. 2005              |     4
 3     | Toyota | 2001; Ptrol; 1.8 TDI |     5
 4.1-2 | Opel   | (model) 1. Vectra    |     6
 4.1-2 | Opel   | (year) 2. 2004       |     7
 5.1-3 | Mazda  | Petrol; 1.9; 3-doors |     8
(8 rows)
```

Actually it is enough. However, lets parse our last data:

```
select 
  *, 
  substring(id from '(\d*)\.?.*') as main_id, -- First number before dot
  row_number() over (partition by substring(id from '(\d*)\.?.*')) as secondary_id -- Order inside previous value
from models_t;
```

Result:

```
  id   |  name  |     description      | mt_id | main_id | secondary_id 
-------+--------+----------------------+-------+---------+--------------
 1     | Ford   | Some text            |     1 | 1       |            1
 2.1-3 | Opel   | 1. Astra             |     2 | 2       |            1
 2.1-3 | Opel   | 2. Diesel            |     3 | 2       |            2
 2.1-3 | Opel   | 3. 2005              |     4 | 2       |            3
 3     | Toyota | 2001; Ptrol; 1.8 TDI |     5 | 3       |            1
 4.1-2 | Opel   | (model) 1. Vectra    |     6 | 4       |            1
 4.1-2 | Opel   | (year) 2. 2004       |     7 | 4       |            2
 5.1-3 | Mazda  | Petrol; 1.9; 3-doors |     8 | 5       |            1
(8 rows)
```

At that point we can use columns `main_id` and `secondary_id` to build wanted IDs like `1.1` or `2.3`.

Everything other is up to you.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time :)!

Comment: @axeMaltesse I hope that it was helpful and gave something additional besides to original question :) Good luck.